# sparql select wikidata group_by and concat

Tags: group-by, sparql, group-concat, wikidata

I want to extract a list o players and a list of clubs where it has played, separated by commas.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?playerLabel
(GROUP_CONCAT(?teamLabel  ; separator=',') as ?teams)
WHERE {
  ?player wdt:P106 wd:Q937857 .
  
  ?player wdt:P2574 ?team 
  
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
GROUP BY ?playerLabel
```

I have two problems:

1. I don't get a list of teams for each player, only the name, and variable ?teams empty.
2. If I don't use GROUP CONCAT and GROUP BY I obtain the team id, but I prefer the label of team.

For example 2 players...:

```
playerLabel       teams

Cristiano Ronaldo Sporting Portugal, Manchester U, Real Madrid, Juventus, Manchester U
Leo Messi         Barcelona, PSG
```

At least I need the Concat and group by, even with code...
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You use [P2574](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P2574), which is "National-Football-Teams.com player ID". While National-Football-Teams.com lists all teams a player played for, this data is not accessible through the Wikidata Query Service. But Wikidata itself has a dedicated property for sports team member: [P54](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P54).
So write `?player wdt:P54 ?team` instead of `?player wdt:P2574 ?team`.

Additionaly, you need to add `?team rdfs:label ?teamLabel . filter (lang(?teamLabel)='en')` to be able to use `?teamLabel` in GROUP_CONCAT().

Thus, the full working query looks like this (restricted to US players to avoid query time outs):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?playerLabel (GROUP_CONCAT(?teamLabel  ; separator=',') as ?teams)
WHERE {
  ?player wdt:P106 wd:Q937857 .
  ?player wdt:P27 wd:Q30 . 
  ?player wdt:P54 ?team .
  ?team rdfs:label ?teamLabel . filter (lang(?teamLabel)='en')
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
GROUP BY ?playerLabel
```